# MySQL PDO request not working return "array"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't understant why I can get any file or my json file from it. Could you help me please?

```
$dbhote = '';
$dbutilisateur = "";
$dbpasse = '';
$dbnom = '';


$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhote . ';dbname=' . $dbnom,       $dbutilisateur, $dbpasse);
$query = "Select * FROM livres";

//query result
$books = array();
$sth = $db->query($query);
while( $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  $books[] = $row; // appends each row to the array
  echo $books;
}
echo json_encode($books);
```

I put a echo $books in the loops to see what happen and I only have written: ArrayArray since I have 2 rows in the table.

Comment: `Array` is what you get when you echo an array. You need to output the array's contents manually, or with e.g. `var_dump`.

Comment: What do you see from your `echo json_encode()`?

Comment: To print the contents of an array, you can set the second parameter of `print_r()` to `true` which will print out all the contents in a human readable string. Ex: `echo print_r($books, true)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php